# GeoPoint property ("place:location") isn't passing to Open Graph object

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm creating custom story on Facebook and using Facebook SDK for iOS to share it. Story consists of text, image and GeoPoint on the map. Everything is good with object and action creation and posting, but one thing — I can't figure out how to pass GeoPoint property to object and make it to be presented on the map.

I was trying two approaches:

**1)** **Inheriting Place object and using pre-defined "place:location" property like this:**

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object.provisionedForPost = YES;
// ...
// other properties work perfect
// ...
object[@"place"] = @{ @"location" : @{ @"longitude": @(-58.381667), @"latitude":@(-34.603333)} };
```

This way it just doesn't pass value, in [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) **"place:location"** field is empty. Although, if I hardcode it, map appears in post and it looks like exactly what I need.

**2)** **Creating custom GeoPoint property "location" and trying to pass the same value there:**

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object.provisionedForPost = YES;
// ...
// other properties work perfect
// ...
object[@"data"] = @{
                    @"location": @{
                        @"latitude": latitude, // these are NSNumber objects, but i also
                        @"longitude": longitude // tried to pass NSString objects
                       }
                   };
```

This way value is passed and value for **"myapp_namespace:location"** property appears in Object Browser, but Story just ignores it for some reason and map doesn't show.

In both cases, I went to Story attachments settings and selected Map layout, as well as chose appropriate property as a Highlighted Point. I just can't get why it doesn't accept value in first case and totally ignores value in the second case. I'd appreciate any help with this question and I  think it may be useful for community since I really can't found answer for many hours.

Comment: Have you tried the code samples here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/? Click on the iOS SDK button for iOS samples.

Comment: @MingLi yes, I've looked through it, but not sure that it's about creating custom objects, and I'm confused with this style of assignment `@"Sample Location: Latitude", @"place:location:latitude"`, although I've tried it too. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MingLi the best tutorial that I've found is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph?locale=en_GB#postingobjects). But I haven't found any example with location properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code in your option 1, however, you're currently passing in "latitude" and "longitude" as an NSArray. Try using a string instead:

```
object[@"place"] = @{ @"location" : @{ @"longitude": @"-58.381667", @"latitude": @"-34.603333"} };
```

Comment: Does't work for me too unfortunately. Actually, I was trying to pass coordinates as both NSString and NSNumber, but "place:location" column is still blank in Object Browser. Also I'm wondering why it doesn't throw error during posting since this property is required for Place subtype object.